# replace columns UNIX with awk

Tags: unix, awk, replace

I want to replace data in spcific column that the user gives with id, with a value that again is given by the user. So the user gives the id of the row, the column, and the value to replace in the column.

i have this code :

```
awk -v antik1=$1 -v antik2=$2 '{sub(/antik1/,"$antik2") ; print }'
persons.dat.txt
```

but when i run it like this

```
./tool.sh Yang POUTSES
```

it gives nothing

persons.dat.txt :

```
933|Mahinda|Perera|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
1129|Carmen|Lepland|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58.781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
4194|Há»“ ChÃ­|Do|male|1988-10-14|2010-03-17T22:46:17.657+0000|103.10.89.118|Internet Explorer
8333|Chen|Wang|female|1980-02-02|2010-03-15T10:21:43.365+0000|1.4.16.148|Internet Explorer
8698|Chen|Liu|female|1982-05-29|2010-02-21T08:44:41.479+0000|14.103.81.196|Firefox
```

Comment: You will have a better result if you supply an example

Comment: this is the program... ill add a little text from persons.dat.txt

Comment: Definitely needs a line or two from persons.data.txt in order to decipher `awk` statement

Comment: How are `$1` and `$2` being set to their values prior to `awk` being called?

Comment: 1) `Yang` doesn't exist in your input file. 2) You don't give your input file name on the same line as the closing `'` of your awk command. 3) Your sub() command is the wrong approach. 4) Your sub() command uses the wrong syntax. Post sample input and expected output that makes sense wrt your awk command's args and explain what you REALLY want to do so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You code does not match your requirement at all:

> the user gives the id of the row, the column, and the value to replace

which I would interpret with

```
awk -v row=2 -v col=3 -v new_value="Hello World" '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "|" }
    NR == row {$col = new_value}
    {print}
' persons.dat.txt
```

Note the use of variables here:

- an unadorned variable is like C, replace with the variable's value (usage of the "row" variable
- the `$` symbol is like an operator that references the value of the field number given by the value (here, "$col")